# Drag UIView between UIViews

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit, drag-and-drop

I have a UIView object X that is contained in an UIView object A. I want to be able to touch X and remove it from object A and move it into object B (another UIView). Both Object A & B are inside of the same super UIView.

```
  A        B
_____    _____
|   |    |   |
| X | -> |   |
|___|    |___|
```

This is what I have so far.

```
@implementation X_UIView

float deltaX;
float deltaY;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.superview.superview addSubview:self]; //pop dragged view outside of container view

    CGPoint beginCenter = self.center;

    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.superview];

    deltaX = touchPoint.x - beginCenter.x;
    deltaY = touchPoint.y - beginCenter.y;
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.superview];

    // Set the correct center when touched 
    touchPoint.x -= deltaX;
    touchPoint.y -= deltaY;

    self.center = touchPoint;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //discover view that event ended was over and add self as a subview.
}

@end
```

Comment: Did you ever complete this? I'm trying to do exactly the same but when I add X to the topmost parent as you do in touchesBegan it disappears. So I'm not able to see the view as I drag it around. Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call `[[touches anyObject] locationInView: self.superview]` to get the point under the finger in the container view. Then send `self.superview -hitTest:withEvent:` to find out the view X is inside. Note that it will always return X, so you will have to override either `-pointIsInside:withEvent:` or `-hitTest:withEvent:` to return nil while you're dragging. This kind of kludge is the reason I would implement such tracking in the container view, rather than in a dragged view.

Comment: How would you implement the tracking in the container view?

Comment: On a second thought, there are perfectly valid reasons to do all tracking in X, so nevermind. By the way, while tracking you can test frames of X and B for intersection instead of checking where the finger is. Depending on your needs, it might be even better for visual feedback.

Answer (score 2):

With Swift 5 and iOS 12, you can solve your problem with Drag and Drop APIs. The following sample code shows how to do.

---

*ViewContainer.swift*

```
import MobileCoreServices
import UIKit

enum ViewContainerError: Error {
    case invalidType, unarchiveFailure
}

class ViewContainer: NSObject {

    let view: UIView

    required init(view: UIView) {
        self.view = view
    }

}
```

```
extension ViewContainer: NSItemProviderReading {

    static var readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider = [kUTTypeData as String]

    static func object(withItemProviderData data: Data, typeIdentifier: String) throws -> Self {
        if typeIdentifier == kUTTypeData as String {
            guard let view = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? UIView else { throw ViewContainerError.unarchiveFailure }
            return self.init(view: view)
        } else {
            throw ViewContainerError.invalidType
        }
    }

}
```

```
extension ViewContainer: NSItemProviderWriting {

    static var writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider = [kUTTypeData as String]

    func loadData(withTypeIdentifier typeIdentifier: String, forItemProviderCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void) -> Progress? {
        if typeIdentifier == kUTTypeData as String {
            do {
                let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: view, requiringSecureCoding: false)
                completionHandler(data, nil)
            } catch {
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }
        } else {
            completionHandler(nil, ViewContainerError.invalidType)
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

---

*ViewController.swift*

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let redView = UIView()
    let greenView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let blueView = UIView()
        blueView.backgroundColor = .blue

        greenView.backgroundColor = .green
        greenView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        greenView.addSubview(blueView)
        setConstraintsInSuperView(forView: blueView)

        redView.backgroundColor = .red
        redView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let greenViewDropInteraction = UIDropInteraction(delegate: self)
        let greenViewDragInteraction = UIDragInteraction(delegate: self)
        greenViewDragInteraction.isEnabled = true
        greenView.addInteraction(greenViewDragInteraction)
        greenView.addInteraction(greenViewDropInteraction)

        let redViewDropInteraction = UIDropInteraction(delegate: self)
        let redViewDragInteraction = UIDragInteraction(delegate: self)
        redViewDragInteraction.isEnabled = true
        redView.addInteraction(redViewDragInteraction)
        redView.addInteraction(redViewDropInteraction)

        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [greenView, redView])
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.frame = view.bounds
        stackView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    }

}
```

```
extension ViewController {

    // MARK: Helper methods

    func setConstraintsInSuperView(forView subView: UIView) {
        subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[subView]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["subView": subView]))
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-[subView]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["subView": subView]))
    }

}
```

```
extension ViewController: UIDragInteractionDelegate {

    func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession) -> [UIDragItem] {
        guard let containedView = interaction.view?.subviews.first else { return [] }
        let viewContainer = ViewContainer(view: containedView)
        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: viewContainer)
        let item = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
        item.localObject = viewContainer.view
        return [item]
    }

    func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, sessionWillBegin session: UIDragSession) {
        guard let containedView = interaction.view?.subviews.first else { return }
        containedView.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, previewForLifting item: UIDragItem, session: UIDragSession) -> UITargetedDragPreview? {
        guard let containedView = interaction.view?.subviews.first else { return nil }
        return UITargetedDragPreview(view: containedView)
    }

    func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, item: UIDragItem, willAnimateCancelWith animator: UIDragAnimating) {
        animator.addCompletion { _ in
            guard let containedView = item.localObject as? UIView else { return }
            interaction.view!.addSubview(containedView)
            self.setConstraintsInSuperView(forView: containedView)
        }
    }

    func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, prefersFullSizePreviewsFor session: UIDragSession) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

```
extension ViewController: UIDropInteractionDelegate {

    func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
        return session.canLoadObjects(ofClass: ViewContainer.self) && session.items.count == 1
    }

    func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession) -> UIDropProposal {
        let dropLocation = session.location(in: view)
        let operation: UIDropOperation
        if interaction.view!.frame.contains(dropLocation) && session.localDragSession != nil {
            operation = .move
        } else {
            operation = .cancel
        }
        return UIDropProposal(operation: operation)
    }

    func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {
        session.loadObjects(ofClass: ViewContainer.self) { viewContainers in
            guard let viewContainers = viewContainers as? [ViewContainer], let viewContainer = viewContainers.first else { return }
            interaction.view!.addSubview(viewContainer.view)
            self.setConstraintsInSuperView(forView: viewContainer.view)
        }
    }

}
```

---

[image]