# Drag copy between UIViews

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I am essentially trying to do what is covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842447/drag-uiview-between-uiviews), but copy instead of move.

Here is what the view hierarchy looks like (copied from the existing question). **A** and **B** are both inside a common superview. **X** is a view inside **A**.

```
  A        B
_____    _____
|   |    |   |
| X | -> |   |
|___|    |___|
```

I want to copy **X** into **B**. **A** is a list of available items. I want to choose an item from **A** and add a copy of it to **B**.

This is what I have come up with so far. After detecting a touch in **X**, I make a copy of the view (viewCopy). Then I add viewCopy to A and add the original view to the superview of **A** and **B**. This is because the touches are probably active on the original view and not on the copied view. I want the new (copied) view to respond to drag for a smooth transition from **A** to **B**.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{        
    id viewCopy = [self mutableCopy];
    [self.superview.superview addSubview:self];
    [self.superview addSubview:viewCopy];
    [viewCopy release];
}
```

This obviously does not work. It is a very crude try, but I am not sure how to go about doing this. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

UIView doesn’t adhere to the NSCopying protocol, so attempting to copy it is likely failing—it’s hitting the base NSObject `-mutableCopy`, which doesn’t do what you want. To get your clone view, you’ll have to recreate it. Easiest way to handle that is to either set up your X view so it can load from a XIB or implement it as a custom UIView subclass that can set up its own contents.

For an example of the former, check out [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW20); the example is for loading custom table view cells, but the technique’s easily applicable to a generic custom view.

Comment: I made my custom view follow the NSCopying protocol and then implemented the copy functions myself. The copy function involves creating a fresh view and setting all the instance variables. I am actually not sure how to handles the touches and which view will respond to the touch, the original one or the copied one that is placed at the same location?