# Programmatically Drag and drop UIImage Between views in iOS

Tags: ipad, uiview, ios4, drag-and-drop, uiimageview

Is it possible to programmatically drag an UIImageView[with UIImage on it] from one UIView and drop on to other UIView?

Waiting for the reply.

Thank You, Suse

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically achieve this by detecting the touches on UIImageView(by subclassing it) and changing the frames of UIImageView to be Y UIView from X UIView.

This Particular SO thread solves the similar problem.
[Drag UIView between UIViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842447/drag-uiview-between-uiviews)