# Setting a view alpha

Tags: uiview, uiimageview, alpha

I have view1 which is an `UIImageView` and I also have view2 which is a subview of view1 and is a `UIImageView` too.

I want to move view2 around and I would like it to have alpha=0 where view1 (his superview) has `alpha!=1`, is that possible? how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

possible to move/drag view2 through different ways.

Use UItouch delegates to do it.. touchesBegan, touchesMoved,touchesEnded,touchesCancelled etc..

You can do it 2 diffrents ways.

1.Create a child class which is inherited from UiView named as view2 and implement the above touch delegate and create its obj and add as the subview of your view1.Then you can get the touch delegate working when touch occurred in view2.

in touchesBegan,touchesMoved delegates, do the coding for drag opertaions.

2.in main view touchesBegan,touchesMoved delegates, check the if touch point intersect the view2 frame.
  if yes,do the code for view2 drag

for drag and drop please see the below links

[drag-uiview-between-uiviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842447/drag-uiview-between-uiviews)

[how-to-drag-and-drop-images](http://iphoneapplicationdevelopers.blogspot.in/2011/03/iphone-how-to-drag-and-drop-images-in.html)

[MoveMe : Apple developer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoveMe/introduction/Intro.html)

For setAlpha, you can use UIView method yourUiView.setAlpha = 1.0 or yourUiView.setAlpha = 0.0 as per your conditions