# CLIENT APP ERROR - Neither the view or container of the UITargetedPreview is currently in a window

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am requesting help with a UIKit warning in the Xcode console I am trying to fix:

> **CLIENT APP ERROR - Neither the view or container of the UITargetedPreview is currently in a window. This is in violation of UIDragInteraction API contract and can cause a severe visual glich.**

I have a Drag Source of a `UITableView` which implements `UITableViewDragDelegate`. The table view is within a Split View Master View, the destination is within the Split View Controller. The drag and drop interaction works perfectly. The problem is the rather scary error from Xcode!

The `UIDragItem` is generated by:

```
extension Store: NSItemProviderWriting {  

    var dragItem: UIDragItem {  
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: NSItemProvider(object: self))  
        dragItem.localObject = self  
        dragItem.previewProvider = {  
            let image = UIImageView(image: self.imageFront)  
            image.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40) // magic number for store preview size  
            return UIDragPreview(view: image)  
        }  
        return dragItem  
    }  
}
```

I have tried to break on all the `UIDragDelegate` methods but the warning appears as the preview is generated, which seems to be later in the process.

I will post my drag methods to see if I am missing anything.

Thanks in advance.

```
// MARK: - Table view drag delegate  

extension StoresTableViewController: UITableViewDragDelegate {  
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {  
        return [stores[indexPath.row].dragItem]  
    }  

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dragSessionWillBegin session: UIDragSession) {  
        guard let draggedStore = session.items.first?.localObject as? Store else { return }  
        if draggedStore.maxSimilarStores > session.items.count {  
            tableView.performBatchUpdates({  
                let index = stores.firstIndex(of: draggedStore)!  
                stores.remove(at: index)  
                stores.insert(draggedStore.copy() as! Store, at: index)  
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .fade)  
            }, completion: nil)  
        }  
    }  

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForAddingTo session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> [UIDragItem] {  
        guard let draggedStore = session.items.first?.localObject as? Store else { return [] }  
        let tableStore = stores[indexPath.row]  
        if draggedStore.name == tableStore.name && draggedStore.maxSimilarStores > session.items.count {  
            return [tableStore.dragItem]  
        } else {  
            return []  
        }  
    }  

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dragPreviewParametersForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIDragPreviewParameters? {  
        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? StoreTableViewCell else { return nil }  
        let parameters = UIDragPreviewParameters()  
        parameters.visiblePath = UIBezierPath(rect: cell.storeImageView.frame)  
        return parameters  
    }  
}
```

I have created a debug project to reproduce:

https://github.com/atapp/iTOLD_DEBUG

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this was to abandon the `UITableViewDragDelegate` and implement a drag interaction from a custom `UITableViewCell`. I am not sure if this is the correct method but it has cleared the error.

For a simple demo of Drag and Drop this answer from ***Imanou Petit*** [Drag UIView between UIViews](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48968516/1817264) I found useful. And obviously the apple docs [Making a View into a Drag Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/making_a_view_into_a_drag_source)

The clue for me was in the error itself, complaining of the lack of view or container for the `UITargetedPreview`. From what I can see `UITargetedPreview` is not part of the `UITableViewDelegate` system, I'm assuming because the `UITableViewDelegate` system is purely designed for drawing and dropping inside the `UITableView` itself.

My use is different, I am trying to drag from a `UITableView` to anywhere.

### **TLDR;**

The new `UITableView` removes all `UITableViewDragDelegate` methods and adds the required custom cell initializers:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StoreCell", for: indexPath) as! StoreTableViewCell
        let dragInteraction = UIDragInteraction(delegate: cell)
        cell.addInteraction(dragInteraction)
        cell.store = stores[indexPath.row]
        {...}
        return cell
    }
```

The custom `UITableViewCell` is:

```
class StoreTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var store: Store?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    {...}
}

extension StoreTableViewCell: UIDragInteractionDelegate {
    func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession) -> [UIDragItem] {
        if let dragItem = store?.dragItem {
            return [dragItem]
        }
        return []
    }

    func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, previewForLifting item: UIDragItem, session: UIDragSession) -> UITargetedDragPreview? {
        if let store = store, let frontImage = store.imageFront {
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: frontImage)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
            let target = UIPreviewTarget(container: storeImageView, center: session.location(in: storeImageView))
            let parameters = UIPreviewParameters()
            parameters.backgroundColor = .clear
            let preview = UITargetedDragPreview(view: imageView, parameters: parameters, target: target)
            return preview
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Note the `UIPreviewTarget` being the image in the custom `UITableViewCell` (although I expect this can be any view) and I set the preview centre from the `UIDragSession` centre.